# Creating a scroll-able level selecting menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am developing a native android app and I want to implement a scroll-able menu for selecting a specific level. I know that I can use fragments for this, but there are 15 levels so I have to create many fragments and layouts. I want to achieve this by some thing simple and more manageable.

I have attached the images for better understanding of what I want!

Hope you answer this question soon. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) to achieve that.